# How can I avoid our users not having multi tab?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a web application and one of our problem is multi-tab of users causes a lot of issues. Can we handle it in server side or by javascript?
Thanks,

Comment: Explain the scenario for _multi-tab of users_ ?

Comment: my guess: he is trying to change the way the browser works. having a second screen opened in a new tab, rather than a new window, and such. not sure, though.

Comment: Well it's clear as it is. When some users need so many stuff done at the same time they tend to open more screen. This can affect the application multiple ways. See a case where users open same screen in two tabs and doing same function on pre-generated same screen state.

Comment: For example, one user is log in. In one window two tabs are open with url of "http://webapp.com/home" and "http://webapp.com/editprofile".

Comment: If the user opens a new tab from the first one to edit profile . then you can't stop it as it is the browser functionality . you can bloc right clicks as you can

Comment: make you server faster or use ajax so people don't have to wait on your machine to move so their screen can move...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

Here is a way to  do it:

1. Create a cookie in `$(document).ready` by firstly checking whether it exists or not, say cookie `name='pg_loaded'` and `value='true'`.
2. The Important part lies here, check that cookie name and value in `$(document).ready(function()` if the cookie value exists then redirect user to another page ex: `NoserviceProvide.html` using `window.location.href`
3. Otherwise The page is loaded for first time so create cookie as explained in step1.
4. Be sure to remove cookie on page `unload` event.

However using cookies will not be flaw proof because user can edit(tamper) them using browser tools. Also it'll not restrict user to have multi-tab environment **but it'll allow your app to run in single tab**.

Or for simplicity use `window.open()` with required settings. But it cant gurantee if user opens another tab.

Hope it helps. cheers :)!

Comment: @dolf, It'll be nice if it works for you. Inform me in both the cases if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is, when a user comes to your site and login, if the user has already logged in avoid the new login with a message.
This can be done in server side. 
Read on HttpSessionListener.
There catch the above mentioned case and do as required for your app.